# Detect interactive use of `kill-buffer` in `kill-buffer-hook`

Tags: hooks, interactive, kill-buffer

As per title, I want to define a kill buffer hook with the variable `kill-buffer-hook` and the function should be able to detect when `(kill-buffer )` has been called interactively.

Is this possible?

The use case is in that I'd like to control the buffer displayed after killings. 
Anyway, there are a lot of hidden buffers opened and killed in the background, which should not trigger the hook actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test the variable `this-command` to see whether it is `kill-buffer`

Comment: Perfect! Just want to add I realized I need to test for `kill-this-buffer` too, for the cases when the buffer is killed from the menubar/toolbar. There is always a way in Emacs)